# What was PHP's "o" serialization format for?

Tags: php, php-internals, language-history

The list of backwards-incompatible changes for PHP 7.4 contain [the following note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php#migration74.incompatible.core.serialization):

> ## Serialization
>
> The o serialization format has been removed. As it is never produced by PHP, this may only break unserialization of manually crafted strings.

*(Note that this is referring to a little-`o`, not the big-`O` format which is used for object serialization.)*

It seems this was never generated by PHP's `serialize()` function, but the fact that this note exists implies that it *was* recognised by the `unserialize()` function.

I've done a [little test fiddle](https://3v4l.org/UIoRu) <sub>(3v4l.org)</sub> which shows this was not simply a synonym for big-`O`, which would be one obvious possibility.

The fiddle exposes the changes in PHP by the differences in the error message that is output.  In PHP >= 7.4 we get an error at position 0 (where the `o` is encountered) whereas prior to 7.4 the error was reported at position 5 (where the data is located).  This implies that `o` was recognised but the data is in the wrong format, which ties in with what I've already deduced, above.

So, what was the `o` serialization format, what did it deserialize to and why did PHP support such a feature if it didn't actually generate it, itself?

Comment: Related? http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php5/classes_objects/serialization.html

Comment: @Caramiriel No.  I am familiar with that page - it is a great resource about the internals of PHP serialization - but It doesn't mention the little-`o` notation at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Originally, PHP 3 used `o:<num_fields>:{<fields>}` to serialize objects.

The following program works in PHP 4.0.0, which can be downloaded from [php.net/releases/index.php](https://php.net/releases/index.php) (the Windows binary still works on Windows 10!):

```
<?php

var_dump(unserialize('o:0:{}'));
```

Output:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.0.0
Content-type: text/html

object(stdClass)(0) {
}
```

I was able to trace the original implementation of the object serialization format to [this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/83de88e90c9b7afa40471486b7b2603a00ac6c2f) in 1999.
See [php3api_var_serialize](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/83de88e90c9b7afa40471486b7b2603a00ac6c2f/ext/standard/var.c#L161).

Later that year, the object serialization format was [changed](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/3491633aa0aa1de359958394214421d7737ae68f) to include the classname of the object being serialized in preparation for PHP 4.
This commit changed the serialization format to `o:<classname_length>:"<class_name>":<num_fields>:{<fields>}`

This made the output of PHP3 and PHP4 incompatible: PHP4 would not have been able to unserialize objects serialized with PHP3.
Therefore, [another commit was added](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/6ecd417b34bd5b957e0f9b76610f94421f38d955) that changed `o` to `O` (lowercase o to uppercase O).
`o` was still supported by `unserialize()` to unserialize objects serialized with PHP3, but `serialize()` did not use `o` anymore.

In 2000, the serialization/unserialization code [was refactored](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/f341f630d3fe6fe669f6a4cbf176f7a5e6f3f4db), resulting in the [file we see today](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.23/ext/standard/var_unserializer.re).

What probably happened is that the compatibility layer broke somewhere along the way, and no-one cared enough about PHP3 compatibility to fix it.
The code in the beginning no longer works with any PHP version released in the last 15 years.

Comment: This is a really useful answer, that points to the details about what the little-o notation was used for.  It doesn't answer the 'why' part of the question, but perhaps that is lost in the mists of time.  I will leave this open for a little while, but if no-one is able to provide any further information I will probably accept this as the answer.

Comment: @HappyDog I updated the answer after diving into the old PHP codebase. Still not sure if I answered your question, but it should be close now :)

Comment: Wow - with your update, this is an amazing answer!  So much detail, and exactly the kind of historical information I was looking for.  In fact, it's so good, I'm going to award a bounty for it, even though your answer is already posted!

Comment: Bounty awarded.  I also added a note to the PHP migration notes, referencing your answer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php#125717